# management database intervention from an administrator

Tags: database, database-administration

given the following question:

**What are two possible classes of intervention that an administrator of a system database 
could take to improve the performance of a query?**

What is a possible answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first consider that DB optimizations are fairly dependent from the DB type/vendor, but here's a short list:

- Fetch the "Explain plan" of the query (if your db let you do this): this is useful to understand what the DB does (using indexes, for instances) to retrieve the query results
- If your query is filtering on attributes with small cardinality, create a [Bitmap Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) on these to speed up retrieving of table rows
- If your query is using joins and your DB supports this, use a Join Index
- If your query is retrieving results against a portion of a table identified by a single attribute, you could use [Sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)